# Json array in Java

Tags: java, json

I have a JSON array:

```
**
**
 {
      "Required" : true,
      "Validation" : {
        "MaxChars" : "40"
        "MinChars" : "10"
      }
  }
**
**
```

The code now:

```
 JSONObject formField = formListAdapter.formArray.getJSONObject(i);

 if(formField.has("Required") && formField.getBoolean("Required") == true){

 }
```

With the aforementioned code, I can check if in the JSON there is a field with the name "Required" and if this is true. But how can check if the Validation has an attribute inside? and how can I check the name and the value of it?
I.e. how can I check the number of the MaxChars or MinChars?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [JSONObject#getJSONObject](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#getJSONObject%28java.lang.String%29) to get the JSONObject corresponding to the key and then you can perform the same operations to get the values from the key.

```
JSONObject validationObject = formField.getJSONObject("Validation");
```

or you can use a better way, Use [jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/)

Answer (score 1):

```
JSONObject validationObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("Validation");
if (validationObject.has("MaxChars")) {
   int maxChars = validationObject.getInt("MaxChars");
   ...
}

// same for MinChars
```

To get the attribute names for `validationObject`, you can use:

```
String[] names = JSONObject.getNames(validationObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to check the values of the "Validiation" object. 
I never had worked with json.org but i belive you can create a new JSONObject from it and read the values like you work with the object in the array.

Answer (score 0):

You want [JSONObject.getJSONObject(String field)](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#getJSONObject%28java.lang.String%29) to get the enclosed JSON object.